# Apple iOS Safari Extension Permission

Tags: ios, safari, safari-extension

I've developed a **Safari Extension for iOS** and in order to use that extension, it needs to enable the permission from Safari Settings in the **Settings screen**. I need to know whether there is a nice way to allow the user to allow permission. Is there any way that I can enable the permissions directly from my **Safari Extension iOS app** so that the user doesn't get confused and end up not allowing the permission. Or if I can navigate the user to the permission screen in Settings directly? Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The user can also give permission to the extension from Safari, without having to navigate to the settings. Like that: https://www.joinhoney.com/en/mobile/ext/enable/ (Must open on iOS safari)

Comment: Any examples how to show additional permissions requested banner at the top?